# If I create 100 daily EBS volume snapshots and the fifth one is inconsistent, how does this affect the others?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, snapshot, amazon-ebs

Let's say something was written to that volume after the snapshot was initiated. That data is not saved, but it will be saved on the next snapshot, right?

Follow-up question: What if the write corrupted the data because it happened just as the snapshot was being created, will all the following snapshots have the corrupted data on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The snapshot is at a point in time. Everything that is altered after that point will NOT be captured in the current snapshot but will be captured in subsequent snapshots.

Not sure how the write would corrupt the data. In theory, the snapshot operation is orthogonal on using the volume, so data corruption due to the snapshot should not happen.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I wonder why so many people argue about inconsistent snapshots then, if snapshots are safe?

Comment: I think there are 2 things here you need to think about. The first one is the data the is on the volume itself. The other one is the data your application has in memory / is caching. If I understand it correctly most problems arise from the application and/or the OS caching things and not having those things fully flushed to disk at the moment of the snapshot. The app might have problems recovering if a snapshot is restored and it's missing parts that were not flushed to disk. This varies from app to app but the bottom line is that these issues don't happen because of the snapshot itself.